# actors vs normal objects

Tags: akka, actor

From a book on reactive applications using akka actors:

> Because system components react to messages only when they are received, the system can use available
>   threads to run the parts of the application that must presently react to message stimuli. All the while,
>   components that are not currently reacting to messages are not utilizing precious CPU resources.

But same can be said about normal objects which are not actors. They consume threads only when asked to do something. How are actors different from normal objects then?

Answer (score 0):

(For "object", you should generally read that as "object, as implemented and used in most OO languages")

I don't think it's that accurate to say that "objects consume threads only when asked to do something": it's more accurate to say that threads consume objects rather than vice versa.  But whichever way we view the arrow of consumption, it's important to note that it's unrestricted: an object can consume/be consumed by arbitrarily many threads at a given point in time and a thread can consume/be consumed by arbitrarily many objects at a given point in time.

Consider the following Scala code:

```
class A(private var b: B) {
  def doSomethingWithB(): Unit = {
    b.doSomething()
  }
}

class B(private var x: Int) {
  def doSomething(): Unit = {
    x += 1
  }
}

def foo(a: A): Unit = {
  // yadda yadda yadda
  a.doSomethingWithB()
}
```

A thread enters `foo` and consumes `a` by calling `doSomethingWithB`.  While still consuming `a`, it consumes `a.b` by calling `doSomething`.  It stops consuming `a.b`, and then stops consuming `a`.

For an actor system, both of those 1:N cardinalities are 1:at-most-one.

Obviously, we can make the object implementation have actor-like constraints: if every public means of using the object requires obtaining a lock, then no more than one thread can consume/be-consumed-by an object.  For the second constraint meanwhile, we can restrict that by, for instance:

```
// simplified without references to things like ExecutionContexts
class A(...) {
  def doSomethingWithB(): Future[Unit] = {
    Future.successful(b).flatMap(_.doSomething())
  }
}

class B(...) {
  def doSomething(): Future[Unit] = {
    x += 1
    Future.successful(())
  }
}

def foo(a: A): Future[Unit] = {
  a.doSomethingWithB()
}
```

Now when calling `doSomethingWithB`, the calling thread doesn't (in general) consume `a.b`: consumption of `a.b` (by calling `doSomething`) happens in either a different thread or perhaps (if the original thread is just a worker thread in a thread pool) in the calling thread after it has returned from `foo`.

Needless to say, this is a fairly unnatural style in OO (and Scala is perhaps the language where this is the most ergonomic, largely because the standard library `Future` implementation is very similar to an actor system implementation).